# Differences between using json and jsonP

Tags: ajax, extjs, jsonp, store

i had a simple controller to update my truck list in my db. Iniatially it had been working with jsonP(because my server was in another domain), and it worked fine, but then i had joined the php scripts(to manage crud in db) in the same domain and i had changed to ajax proxy. The problem is that i had noticed although ajax proxy sends POST request... i never get anything... (These never occurs with jsonp, because it sent GET request i think). So, is there anything i had forgotten or i must do?

Let me show my store before and after the upgrade:

BEFORE:

```
Ext.define('myapp.store.ListaCamiones', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'myapp.model.Camion'
],

constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        model: 'myapp.model.Camion',
        storeId: 'ListaCamiones',
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            api: {
                read: 'http://myapp.localhost/camion/listar',
                write: 'http://myapp.localhostt/camion/guardar/',
                update: 'http://myapp.localhost/camion/guardar/',
                destroy: 'http://myapp.localhost/camion/eliminar/'
            },
            url: 'http://myapp.localhost/camion/listar',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'listacamion'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'listacamion'
            }
        }
    }, cfg)]);
}
});
```

AFTER:

```
Ext.define('myapp.store.ListaCamiones', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'myapp.model.Camion'
],

constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        model: 'myapp.model.Camion',
        storeId: 'ListaCamiones',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/camion/listar',
            api: {
                read: '/camion/listar',
                write: '/camion/guardar/',
                update: '/camion/guardar/',
                destroy: '/camion/eliminar/'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'listacamion'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'listacamion'
            }
        }
    }, cfg)]);
}
});
```

This is what i got from chrome debug:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/x-json
Date:Mon, 01 Jul 2013 15:40:38 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.9-4ubuntu2
```

I hope you can help me to understand what is happening . Thank you in advance

Comment: what do you get in your logs on server side? are the ajax requests reaching the end points as you expect?

Comment: 192.168.100.150 - - [01/Jul/2013:12:10:04 -0500] "POST /index/login HTTP/1.1" 200 412
192.168.100.150 - - [01/Jul/2013:12:10:31 -0500] "POST /camion/eliminar/?_dc=1372698624678 HTTP/1.1" 200 231   This what i got... What could be happening? @amol ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing your proxy type to 'rest'